# How to split time slots into day wise slots using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, datetime

Any help will be really appreciated! I'm trying from 4 days but still not found any solution. Please help me. Guide me for library or methods i can use.

Here is the given input. array of session start and end. I want to calculate daily usage period. So i want to split each slot in their own day.

```
var slots = [
  { start: dayjs('2019-01-01 21:00:00'), end: dayjs('2019-01-01 23:00:00') },
  { start: dayjs('2019-01-01 22:00:00'), end: dayjs('2019-01-02 01:00:00') },
  { start: dayjs('2019-01-01 22:00:00'), end: dayjs('2019-01-02 04:00:00') },
  { start: dayjs('2019-01-01 21:00:00'), end: dayjs('2019-01-02 00:00:00') },
  { start: dayjs('2019-01-02 00:00:00'), end: dayjs('2019-01-02 04:00:00') },
  { start: dayjs('2019-01-02 01:00:00'), end: dayjs('2019-01-02 04:00:00') },
  { start: dayjs('2019-01-31 01:00:00'), end: dayjs('2019-02-01 04:00:00') },
]
var output = []

slots.forEach((slot) => {
  // filter same slots with same day
  if (slot.start.isSame(slot.end, 'day')) {
    output.push(slot)
  } else {
  // what to do here? how to split end time
  }
})
console.log(output)
```

I need this kind of output

```
[
  { start: '2019-01-01 21:00:00', end: '2019-01-01 23:00:00' },
  { start: '2019-01-01 22:00:00', end: '2019-01-01 23:59:59' },
  { start: '2019-01-02 00:00:00', end: '2019-01-02 01:00:00' },
  { start: '2019-01-01 22:00:00', end: '2019-01-01 23:59:59' },
  { start: '2019-01-02 00:00:00', end: '2019-01-02 04:00:00' },
  { start: '2019-01-01 21:00:00', end: '2019-01-01 23:59:59' },
  { start: '2019-01-02 00:00:00', end: '2019-01-02 00:00:00' },
  { start: '2019-01-02 00:00:00', end: '2019-01-02 04:00:00' },
  { start: '2019-01-02 01:00:00', end: '2019-01-02 04:00:00' },
  { start: '2019-01-31 01:00:00', end: '2019-01-31 23:59:59' },
  { start: '2019-02-01 00:00:00', end: '2019-02-01 04:00:00' },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea would be to iteratively split a time slot into two, the first going from the start of the time slot to the end of the day of the start time, and the second going from the start of the next day of the start time (add a day) to the end time.

```
{ start: dayjs('2019-01-01T22:00:00-00:00'), end: dayjs('2019-01-02T01:00:00-00:00') }
```

becomes

```
[
  { start: dayjs('2019-01-01T22:00:00-00:00'), end: dayjs('2019-01-02T23:59:59-00:00') },
  { start: dayjs('2019-01-02T00:00:00-00:00'), end: dayjs('2019-01-02T01:00:00-00:00') }
]
```

Note, it appears that `dayjs` uses full DateTime format by default.

Algorithm [Updated with new info about multi-day slots from @asissuthar]

```
const slotHopper = { ...slot }; // don't mutate original slot
while (!slotHopper.start.isSame(slotHopper.end, "day")) {
  // peel off first day of slot
  const splitSlot = {
    start: slotHopper.start,
    end: dayjs(slotHopper.start).endOf("day")
  };
  acc.push(splitSlot);
  // update start to beginning of next day
  slotHopper.start = dayjs(slotHopper.start)
    .add(1, "day")
    .startOf("day");
}
acc.push(slotHopper);
```

I extracted the above into a reducer function in the following sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/lp0z5x7zw9, where `acc` is the accumulation array for the result.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese !! Your code will work only for one day gap but if slot have value like `{ start: dayjs("2019-02-01 01:00:00"), end: dayjs("2019-02-04 04:00:00") }` above code will not work properly.

Comment: You used `endOf` and `startOf` functions. That's really very helpful hint for me.

Comment: Thanks @asissuthar.  True, I hadn't thought about existing slots longer than a day, but I only had your sample data to go on.  Glad I could help.  If my answer was sufficient for you I'd appreciate it being accepted.  Thanks.

Comment: @asissuthar Updated my algorithm to reflect multi-day slots.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). I don't know `dayjs`. I'm assuming you're using it only to compare the date part and it's not part of the original array. So, instead I have created a function which gives just the `date` part for `start` and `end`.

```js
const slots = [
  { start: '2019-01-01 21:00:00', end: '2019-01-01 23:00:00' },
  { start: '2019-01-01 22:00:00', end: '2019-01-02 01:00:00' },
  { start: '2019-01-01 22:00:00', end: '2019-01-02 04:00:00' },
  { start: '2019-01-01 21:00:00', end: '2019-01-02 00:00:00' },
  { start: '2019-01-02 00:00:00', end: '2019-01-02 04:00:00' },
  { start: '2019-01-02 01:00:00', end: '2019-01-02 04:00:00' },
  { start: '2019-01-31 01:00:00', end: '2019-02-01 04:00:00' }];
  
const getDay = (date) => date.split(" ")[0];

const newArray = slots.reduce((acc, {start,end}) => {
    if (getDay(start) != getDay(end))
        acc.push({ start, end: `${getDay(start)} 23:59:59` }, 
                 { start: `${getDay(end)} 00:00:00`, end });
    else
        acc.push({ start, end })
    return acc
}, []);

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution. it works perfactly. [Execute](https://codesandbox.io/s/kx48qw7qr3)

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";

const slots = [
  { start: dayjs("2019-01-01 21:00:00"), end: dayjs("2019-01-01 23:00:00") },
  { start: dayjs("2019-01-01 22:00:00"), end: dayjs("2019-01-02 01:00:00") },
  { start: dayjs("2019-01-01 22:00:00"), end: dayjs("2019-01-02 04:00:00") },
  { start: dayjs("2019-01-01 21:00:00"), end: dayjs("2019-01-02 00:00:00") },
  { start: dayjs("2019-01-02 00:00:00"), end: dayjs("2019-01-02 04:00:00") },
  { start: dayjs("2019-01-02 01:00:00"), end: dayjs("2019-01-02 04:00:00") },
  { start: dayjs("2019-01-31 01:00:00"), end: dayjs("2019-02-01 04:00:00") },
  { start: dayjs("2019-02-01 01:00:00"), end: dayjs("2019-02-04 04:00:00") }
];

function splitDayWise(slots) {
  let output = [];

  function pushSlot(slot, start, end) {
    output.push({
      ...slot
    });

    let top = output[output.length - 1];
    top.start = start;
    top.end = end;
    top.time = top.end - top.start;
  }

  slots.forEach(slot => {
    if (slot.start.isSame(slot.end, "day")) {
      pushSlot(slot, slot.start, slot.end);
    } else {
      while (!slot.start.isSame(slot.end, "day")) {
        pushSlot(slot, slot.start, slot.start.endOf("day"));
        slot.start = slot.start.add(1, "day").startOf("day");
      }
      pushSlot(slot, slot.start, slot.end);
    }
  });

  return output;
}

const daywiseSlots = splitDayWise(slots).map(slot => ({
  start: slot.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
  end: slot.end.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
  time: slot.time
}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(daywiseSlots, null, 2));
```